# Integral roots of a circulant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-graph-theory

When does the circulant matrix have only integral roots? 
For example: adjacency matrix for $K_n$ has all the roots integral which is circulant, but in case of Cycle on $n>3$ it is circulant but it may not have an integral roots.